# why my lexical analyzer can not recognize numbers and ids and operators

Tags: flex-lexer

my lexical analyzer in flex can not recognize numbers and ids and operators ,only keywords were recognized where is my mistake? this is my code:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}

Nums  [0-9]
LowerCase  [a-z]
UpperCase  [A-Z]
Letters  LowerCase|UpperCase|[_]
Id  {Letters}({Letters}|{Nums})*
operators  +|-|\|*
%%
"if" {printf("if keyword founded \n");}
"then" {printf("then keyword founded \n");}
"else" {printf("else keyword founded \n");}
Operators {printf(" operator founded \n");}
Id {printf(" id founded ");}
%%
int main (void)
{ yylex(); return(0);}
int yywrap(void)
{ return 1;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a named definition, it ust be enclosed in `{}`.  So your `Letters` rule should be

```
Letters   {LowerCase}|{UpperCase}|[_]
```

... as it is, it matches the literal inputs `LowerCase` and `UpperCase`.  Similarly in your rules, you want

```
{Operators}  ...
{Id}  ...
```

as what you have will match the literal input strings `Operators` and `Id`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `Operators` is equivalent to `"Operators"`, so it only matches that single word. If you meant to expand the macro by that name, the syntax is `{Operators}`. (Actually, `{operators}` since you seem to have inconsistently spelled the macro name in all lower-case.)

If you do that, flex will complain because of the syntax error in that macro. (Syntax errors in macros aren't detected unless the macro is expanded. That's just one of the problems with using macros.)

You have different problems with your other macros. For example, `Nums` doesn't appear in any rule at all.

My suggestion would be to use fewer (or no) macros and more character classes. Eg.:

```
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*  { /* Action for identifier. */ }
[[:digit:]]+               { /* Action for number. */ }
[-+*/]                     { /* Action for operator. */ }
```

Please read the [Patterns section in the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) for a full description of the pattern syntax, including the named character class expressions used in the first two patterns above.